# SDL Content Porter 8 doesnt setup locally?

Tags: web8

I am unable to install Content Porter from client browser (locally) on my machine - personal pc.

I can install and run it from the server itself, but when I attempt to install locally is where it does not work..

This is the error msg: ‘This product requires SDL Tridion Content Manager 2011 SP1 HR2 or SDL Tridion CM 2013 SP1 HR1 pr SDL Web CM 8 to be installed’

Well I don’t have Web 8 installed on my personal pc..

and btw there is no tag on TSE for CP8

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This installer is for server-side only. Client should be installed as a click-once application from CME. It is described [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v1/GUID-D48888F2-94CE-49AB-9923-D5BC9FBE5645)

Comment: Yep. Forgot it needs to be done from IE - hee-haw!